# Scale Object and keep object in same place - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scale, game-development

I have an object That I would like to scale but that the end of the object to still be in the same place.

[My Paste Bin](https://pastebin.com/8ZhSu6x2)

```
IEnumerator Expand()
```

Is the function that makes the object grow.

```
GameObject object;
```

Is the Object that is being scaled.

Comment: Do you have any code that is actually expanding your object and could you add it?

Comment: I fixed my paste bin link

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want, of course the object is still in the same place, you only chagne it's localscale --> you are only making it bigger.

Comment: I want to make it bigger while keeping the end in the same place

Answer (score 0):

Put your object under parent.

Put object in position, so parent's transform is exactly on the point, which should stays where it is while scaling ("the end of the object to still be in the same place").

Scale parent.

Comment: Adding to object to an empty game object did not stay where I wanted it to be.

Comment: Looking at your script, you want to expand the rope. Put rope under empty gameobject. Move rope in such fashion, that rope's end will be right under parents transform (the arrows in editor). Then scale parent.

Comment: Scale depends on the position of your rope (the move/rotate/scale gizmo). Objects scale outwards from that point. The suggested parent is a way to easily modify that position in relation to your rope. When you put rope under a parent you move the rope (in relation to parent position) so that it will scale outward from parent position point - i.e. you set parent where the rope is attached, then move the child rope so its end is at the parent point. Scale parent and your rope will scale outwatd from parent point.